# Selenium webdriver isn't able to clear a field, but is able to send_keys to it

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to create a program that signs up for instagram with a new account, I've got the emails and the rest generated, when I go ahead and send_keys to the appropriate fields, it does it just fine. I wanted to implement a retry function, which would clear the email field and try with a different mail. However this does not work, even though send_keys to it worked previously? Snippet of my code below.

```
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'Email')]").send_keys(mail)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'Full')]").send_keys(name + lastname)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'User')]").send_keys(namae+lastonamae+pamae2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'Password')]").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@type,'submit')]").click()
```

This attempts to create a new account with the appropriate credentials, however when it fails, I want it to try to look for an element that is only present when it fails, and if it finds that, it should clear the email field and retry with a different one. Code below.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/span') #this looks for the element only present on the fail page
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'Email')]").clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'Email')]").send_keys(mail2)
```

It doesn't clear the field, but doesn't raise an error either. It then proceeds to type the 2nd email with no problems. I appreciate any help on the matter.

**EDIT:** **Posting a bigger chunk of the code.**

```
def signup():
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com')
    time.sleep(7)
    if trycounter < 3:  #this is almost always true, just a failsafe
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'Email')]").send_keys(mail1)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'Full')]").send_keys(name + ' ' + lastname)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'User')]").send_keys(name+lastname+extension)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'Password')]").send_keys(password)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@type,'submit')]").click()
            time.sleep(7)  
            try: #this only executes if a popup that wants you to confirm your age pops up
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="igCoreRadioButtonageRadioabove_18"]').click() 
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/button').click()
                    time.sleep(5)
            except:
                    pass
            try:
                    randomgen() #generates the mail,password and name
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/span')
                    time.sleep(1)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'Email')]").clear()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'Email')]").send_keys(mail2)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'User')]").send_keys(username)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@type,'submit')]").click()
                    time.sleep(7)
```

Comment: In your second snippet, the error page check -> That isn't doing anything. It is finding an element, but there is no condition there. Therefore, it is effectively doing nothing at all. Unless you haven't posted all of the code, and that is in some try clause? Based on some of your description, it certainly suggests that. If that is only part of the relevant code, please post all of it.

Comment: i tried the other fields for the same thing and none of them can be cleared with my current code it seems, unsure why.

Comment: So what I am suggesting is to post the full code. All between the first snippet and the second snippet. I can only make assumptions with what you currently have. And with what you currently have, the issue is obvious to me. You have no wait after the "submit" is clicked. Obviously your server is checking to see if it can create this new user. During that time, your code jumps into searching for the error, which can't possibly be there yet. But then, you might have that wait, and just haven't posted all your code. So I don't know.

Comment: posted a bigger chunk of the code, the original code does have sleeps in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code as alternative for clear method:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
email_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'Email')]")
email_element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
email_element.send_keys(mail1)

fullname_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'Full')]")
fullname_element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a') 
fullname_element.send_keys(name + ' ' + lastname)

# do it for other field as well
```

Comment: @Naay : try out this solution and let me know if you face any issue

Answer (score 1):

So this will definitely work as a workaround. I just tried it on instagram. Although there was no field with an aria label called Email for me. It was aria-label "Mobile Number or Email" for me.

```
driver.execute_script("$(\"input[aria-label='Email']"\").value = '';");
```

I will keep looking at it to see why the clear command didn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to delete mail1.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'Email')]").send_keys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'Email')]").send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@aria-label,'Email')]").send_keys(mail2)
```